# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, phpmailer

I'm using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I can't send emails with PHPMailer. But in my local server it works like a charm. AWS Elastic Beanstalk uses Red Hat 4.8.3-9... I tryed all of [diagnose techniques of PHPMailer Troubleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and all work fine... I don't know if the last one "SELinux blocking" is the problem, but my error is not the same.

I try to use `getsebool httpd_can_sendmail` and the response is `getsebool:  SELinux is disabled`.

My error is:

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)

Can you tell me if that's the problem and how I can I fix that?

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1013

Comment: What SMTP server are you trying to connect to? What port are you using?

Comment: @Brian it's a private enterprise SMTP server, I can't share here. Port: 465. But I'm using same smtp with same port on my local server and it's work well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Elastic Beanstalk - MAIL (Sending and receiving emails )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628491/aws-elastic-beanstalk-mail-sending-and-receiving-emails)

Comment: Are there any other log messages before the "Failed to connect to server" message? The fact that you can telnet from your EB instance to port 465 on the SMTP server implies that it's not a connectivity issue, and perhaps something related to SSL as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672960/phpmailer-error-smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server

Comment: @Brian you are right. It's a SSL related problem. We try with another smtp provider and it work's. Probably its something with the certificate.

Answer (score -1):

Elastic beanstalk blocks outbound SMTP by default. The steps in the troubleshooting guide will have shown you this (telnet or openssl connections to port 465 on your server would fail). There isn't really any more to it! Amazon wants you to use SES for email. This is really a duplicate of [AWS Elastic Beanstalk - MAIL (Sending and receiving emails )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628491/aws-elastic-beanstalk-mail-sending-and-receiving-emails)

Comment: No, I have tried all steps and they work fine, i think: http://i.imgur.com/1ovcUZL.png. It is blocked?

Comment: Ok, so post the output you get with SMTPDebug = 3.

Comment: It's a SSL related problem. We try with another smtp provider and it works. Probably it's something with the certificate. Sorry for some inconvenient.